# Magento load product attributes by group?

Tags: php, magento, model-view-controller, orm

Is there way to get into a foreach loop and loop through all the product attributes in an attribute group in Magento? Please check screenshot. For example, I just wanna loop through the values in the attributes of Design group.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/62230/429611/8EOCq5jqCKVUkJR/Screen%20Shot%202014-05-29%20at%204.10.10%20PM.png

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no built in function that will return you with array of product attributes organized by group. This is one of the missing functionalities. You need to create it yourself in a helper or a block class.

[EDIT]

It looks like I was wrong. There is a method that will return you attributes from given group. It is in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getAttributes()`. The first argument there is group id. So you can do something like this:

```
$groupId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_group')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('eq' => $_product->getAttributeSetId()))
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name', array('eq' => 'General'))
    ->getFirstItem()->getId();

foreach($_product->getAttributes($groupId) as $attribute) {
  //this will return text value even for multiselect
  $attributeVal = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);

  //or but you need to handle retriving select and multiselect labels
  $attributeVal = $_product->getData($attribute->getCode());
}
```

This make it easier to get attributes from the group but I think that it still require own helper or, better, own block as that piece of code in phtml file is not the best practice.